# Calculating the value with currency symbols

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

```
Case "Labour"
            TxtBUP1.Text = "£" & "20.00" & "/Hr"

Unitcost = Val(TxtBUP1.Text) * Val(CBQty1.Text)
    TxtBCost1.Text = Str(Unitcost)
    'Individual Cost [Value + Qty]
```

My main focus is calculating the end value with the additional currency symbol (£ and /Hr), so my question to you is basically is there a way to focus the coding primarily on the "20.00", but still show the end output with the **currency sybmols**?

Comment: Drop the legacy VB6 stuff (`Val`, `Str`) and use the built-in .NET functions and formats.  [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0c899ak8%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) has loads of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really don't want/cannot use built-in functions for currency or time formatting and if your data are always with the same format (i.e. `currency symbol` + `value` + `per hour` for this example, but anyway "forecastable"), then you could add to your project:

**A string -> number function**
to "clean" your value from the currency symbol and the "per hour" symbol, to hence return it in double type:

```
Public Function StringToNumber(ByVal stringValue As String) As Double

    stringValue = stringValue.Replace("£", "")
    stringValue = stringValue.Replace("/Hr", "")
    Convert.ToDouble(stringValue)
    Return stringValue

End Function
```

**A number -> string function** to re-write the currency symbol and the "per hour" at the end:

```
Public Function NumberToString(ByVal myValue As Double) As String

    Return "£" & myValue & "/Hr"

End Function
```

Like this, you will be able to perform all the operations you want by simply using these two functions that will allow to convert a data point (to be used into the code) at your pleasure:

```
Public Sub yourProcedure()

    Dim myString As String : myString = "£20.00/Hr"
    MsgBox("If I add 10 GBP per hour, the hourly pay will be " & NumberToString(StringToNumber(myString) + 10))

End Sub
```

This is the idea, if you have custom values such as "currency / value / per hour". I let you manage the possible complexity coming from different currency symbols or different time measures apart for "per hour".